# Android border for button is not working through xml

Tags: android, xml, button, background

I try to put a border for a button in android but unfortunately `android:background=""` dosen't give any chance to put a drawable resource file. Also it dosen't any chance to put a background color.

This is my button ,

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space1"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border" />
```

IDE(Android Studio) brings the error in the last line of the button xml.

And this is my **button_border.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="##662a48" />
</shape>
```

Button should be like below

[image]

How to correct this error ? 
Have any ideas about this problem .

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37183924/3981656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are providing the wrong value i.e. android:color="##662a48"
try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#662a48" />
</shape>
```

Comment: When I used ColorZilla it told me the color codes are #9B1D4C. You can also use this one if you want. Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="270" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#662a48" />
</shape>
```

remove one # @ you stroke color

that is, change

```
#662a48 instead of ##662a48
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use extra XML for that. You can use the default functionality like,

```js
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
           app:strokeColor="#662a48"
           android:text="Submit"
           app:strokeWidth="2dp"
           app:cornerRadius="10dp"/>
```